# Allow user to input value during on start of a windows service vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, windows-services, windows-installer, user-input

I need to get the user input for where they want the files that will be produced by my windows service to be stored.

I was thinking that i could do this by reading in the user's input to a variable in the on start event of my service? this variable is then later used in my xml writer.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Services can no longer interact with the desktop.  They never should have because this is a huge security hole.

The correct design is to put a custom dialog in your installer to input a value from the user that gets stored in a secure custom public property.  Then use this property to update either a registry value or xml key/value pair type attribute.   Then refactor your service class to use that resource as the configuration variation point.

The point is the configuration setting should have been set  long before your service ever tried to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do anything that requires a UI for a service, stop.  This is not a good idea and is highly discouraged.  From what I have seen, people will create a seperate program to modifiy the windows service settings and then restart the service.  Now, if you are just looking for a way to get information that is not hard-coded, I would just use the app.config file to store the settings and then reference it when the service started.  I have seen others use the registry as well, but I can't tell you which way is better.  Here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611(v=vs.80).aspx with a lot of information about My.Settings even if it is a bit dated.  Once you have a setting created it, you will just need to reference it during the onstart event.  So you could do as follows:

```
dim filePath as string = My.Settings.FilePath
```

HTH

Wade

Comment: *"This is not a good idea and is highly discouraged."* Actually, since Windows Vista, it's not possible at all. The last time this giant security hole was open was Windows XP, which surely no one is still running....